# Load video mp4 webpack loader

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack-loader

How to use loader for mp4 video format with webpcak 4, I try like this:

```
       {
            test: /\.mp4$/,
            use: 'file-loader',
            loader: 'file-loader?name=videos/[name].[ext]',
        },
```

and import like this

```
import pressButtonAnimated from './images/pressButtonAnimated.mp4'
```

But it does not work for me, and I get an error `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

But this one is work for me, but I don wanna add in each file

```
import pressButtonAnimated from '-!file-loader!./images/pressButtonAnimated.mp4'
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The way how you declare your loader is not right. You are mixing two ways to define loaders.

```
 {
        test: /\.mp4$/,
        use: 'file-loader?name=videos/[name].[ext]',
 },
```

Could you try this please.

Link:
https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/

Answer (score 3):

with Webpack5, the attributes property has been replaced with `sources`

We can use file-loader like this so we can give it the option name and path.

```
{
    test: /\.mp4$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
                name: "[name].[ext]",
                outputPath: "video"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**also for some reason if you write a video tag in your html**

```
<video class="">
    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**It doesn't load in webpack but we can use html-loader as follow**

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: {
                sources: {
                    list: [
                        {
                            tag: "source",
                            attribute: "src",
                            type: "src"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**also we can use url-loader but it only load the images and videos added through css.**

**PS:** if you found a solution for html tags with src attribute to use it with file-loader it would be great.