# react next.js add video

Tags: reactjs, next.js

./public/video/video-1.mp4
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file) i get this error messeage.

```
import React from "react"
import atb from "../public/video/video-1.mp4"
const Video = () => {
    return (
        
            
        
    )
}
export default Video
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943372/load-video-mp4-webpack-loader

Comment: thank you, the link you provided solved it