Cannot import mp4 filetypes with webpack
I've seen other solutions related to this issue, but none seem to work for me. I'm trying to import an mp4 file using webpack but I get the error that there are no loaders configured to process my file. I import the file like so:
import videoSrcInit from ('../src/ImageSlider/slider_1.mp4');
Here's my webpack.config.js file:
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        assetModuleFilename: '[name][ext]',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(pdf|png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(mov|mp4)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader",
                        options: {
                            sources: {
                                list: [
                                    {
                                        tag: "source",
                                        attribute: "src",
                                        type: "src"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

};```

What I added above was from this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943372/load-video-mp4-webpack-loader 
Unfortunately still not working for me.


Most likely mov|mp4 must be inserted as a (media) resource like png|svg|jpg|jpeg etc.

@VC.One can you clarify? I have tried adding mp4 to my webpack.config.js file as an asset/resource, but that does not work. When doing more research, it was suggested to add it to the file in the way I showed but that is also not working.

I will test your code when I get a chance (it won't be today). It is possible there's nothing wrong with your code (either version) but the problem is actually with the MP4 file itself. Please load a copy of the file at MediaInfo online. There could be problems... (1) If the format is not AVC (where also the codec ID should be avc1) (2) If the color space is not YUV, or (3) If Chroma subsampling is not 4:2:0... Check if your file's values are different to those? Also does code work with a different file?

@VC.One, I was able to get it sorted. The issue ended up being in the way that I was trying to import the videos. For images, I was using "require" to import them asynchronously and thought I could do the same for videos. Still not quite sure why using require doesn't work for video but once I tried importing them normally, I didn't have any issues. (I had tried this already before posting the question but had a typo).
